# Game Theory exercise collection

Tags: reference-request, books

I am looking essentially for a comprehensive collection of exercises of standard topics in Game Theory.

Ideally, I would like to have a big manual organized by equilibrium concept, starting from the very basic NE 2x2 games and going all the way to dynamic games of incomplete information.

Desirable features include solutions, decent (standard and neat) notation, comprehensiveness, no other fluff/explanations apart from exercises.

Comment: Just exercises, or exercises with solutions?

Comment: @VARulle either works well for me

Comment: "Game Theory Evolving" by Gintis is mostly an exercise book.

Answer (score 3):

I like [Tadelis' book](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691129082/game-theory). The [solution manual](http://assets.press.princeton.edu/chapters/sm10001.pdf) includes all exercises, without the rest of the text.

Answer (score 1):

One example of a book that roughly fits your requirements is Erich Prisner: Game Theory Through Examples.

It is mostly introductory book but has very few extra explanations besides a walkthrough of exercises.